# IBM Watson Assistant: chatbot: integration with database

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson

I am building a chatbot using IBM Watson Assistant.How can connect my local server database with that.Please provide step by step solution and code required .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to look at the dialog node functions which allow you to make programmatic calls https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions